# How to efficiently change a very small part of a very large QPixmap?

Tags: qt, graphics

Drawing on a widget in Qt is simple. First you create a QPixmap, assign a QPainter to it, draw with the QPainter, and at the end set the pixmap to the widget.
For example,

```
QPixmap pixmap(ui->label->width(), ui->label->height());
pixmap.fill(background_color);
QPainter painter(&pixmap)
painter.setpen(foreground_color);
//painter.drawLine(....) etc.
ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

So far so good.

However, what if the pixmap is very large, and I have to change a very small portion of it very often? In my case I profiled it to be my bottleneck. Instead of creating a new pixmap and copying the old onto it, we can load the existing pixmap and only make the necessary changes to it. However, it is also still very slow.

```
Pixmap pixmap = *(ui->label->pixmap());  // takes almost zero time
QPainter painter(&pixmap);               // takes up 40% of the time
//draw stuff with painter                // takes almost zero time
ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);            // takes up 60% of the time
```

Even if I re-use the painter so that I don't have to create it again every time, I still have to call `setPixMap(pixmap)`, otherwise the image is not refreshed.

Is there a way around it?

Must I embed an OpenGL window or something similar, or is there a way with just using native Qt classes? Note, that the change in the image is very small and takes up an insignificant amount of time, it's the redrawing of the whole pixmap which is time-consuming. As I don't know beforehand where I'll be making the changes, splitting the pixmap up onto multiple small labels would be very complicated.

Comment: Please update the question with more information on what you're doing. As it is, we can only make assumptions, which we've ascertained are not correct.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight : what information are you interested in? My problem is that calling `setPixmap` can take up to several hundred ms even if I only changed a few pixels in the pixmap, and I'm looking for a way to refresh the displayed image either without calling setPixmap, or in any other way which shouldn't take that much time. The problem is not necessarily when and how often the change is needed, but the individual update time itself is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a large QLabel, then it would be better using a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) and [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html).

The scene allows you to add items, and the view is a widget which is like a window looking into the scene.

You could start by adding a [QGraphicsPixmapItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html), but I think you'd be better off deriving from [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html), storing a QPixmap and rendering the image in its paint function.

Here's an example of the derived class header

```
class MyImage : public QGraphicsItem
{
    public:
        MyImage(QGraphicsItem* parent);

        QRectF boundingRect();

        void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget = 0);

     protected:
         void QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)

     private:
         QPixmap m_pixmap;
}
```

In the paint function, use the QPainter to draw m_pixmap;

Comment: Yes, but how to "make the necessary changes to the image and set it on the label"? Please take a look at my time measurements. The painting itself takes almost no time at all, it's the "setting it on the label" which takes up almost all the time.

Comment: That's because you're setting it in the paint function; don't do that.

Comment: No, I'm not setting it in the `paint()` function. I didn't derive any class from the label and I didn't overload its paint fucntion. I just have a function which is called whenever an event forces me to make changes. My point is to only update part of the image, and `setPixmap` updates the whole image even if only one pixel was changed.

Comment: What's the event that you're responding to?

Comment: It's a mouse press event on an invisible layer on top of the actual layer. As the pixmap takes up my whole screen (or even more, necessitating scrolling), repainting it can take more than 100ms, which introduces a visible lag.